# $_POST in php isn't working

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am creating a register, the database is using phpMyadmin, and I have looked up why the POST isn't working but everything I read as a suggestion doesn't work for me. I am getting no errors, I used REQUEST instead of POST but still no luck

```
require_once('config1.php');

if (isset($_POST) & !empty($_POST)) {
    $username = $_POST['username']; // you should really do some more logic to see if it's set first
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'zz_login' (username, email, password) VALUES 
    ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    if ($result) {
        echo "user registation successful";
    } else {
        echo "user registeration failed";
    }
};
```

I have created a simple form which is here

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="POST">

<input type="text" id="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>

 <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
 <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
 <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>

 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Register</button>
 <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
 </form><!-- /form -->
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ANY `name=` on your form elements.

Comment: `&` on its own is a bitwise operator.

Comment: On top of this, use `&&` instead of `&`, hash your passwords, use prepared statements (sql injections!)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone `&` would also work, but isn't a short circuit operator. In this case the second operand is useless, because `!empty` is pretty the same as `isset`

Comment: Yeah, just pointing it out.

Comment: I tried using && but it didn't work. @Philipp will get round to hashing passwords. What are sql injections?

Comment: use if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')  to check if the form has been posted

Comment: @M_12 you should follow IncredibleHat's suggestion and add the name attribute to your form elements, or they won't be sent to the server. SQL Injections? Think about a user which input something with an `'` inside - they could basically write and execute every on your database. https://www.xkcd.com/327/

Comment: *I am getting no errors* Is this simply because the page has a syntax error, and you not got error reporting on? We presuming that's just a copy and paste to stackoverflow, not that its your actual code.

Comment: There there is something else fundamentally flawed in your code that you have not shown here. As what you have shown here, the two issues are clearly "no name attributes" and "sketchy conditional to check for $_POST". Have you even debugged by doing a `var_dump($_POST);` near the top of your script?

Comment: Also if your html form is not from the same url as the php you are trying to hit... you definitely need to add that to `action="path/to/script.php"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `name` element to all fields. This is what the "this" is in `$_POST['this']`:

```
<form class="form-signin" action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required autofocus>
    <span id="reauth-email" class="reauth-email"></span>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Register</button>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block btn-signin" type="submit">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

Also please escape your variables to prevent SQL injection and do some sort of script validation (javascript will only get you so far as for validation). I'm also not sure how you plan to have both signin and register options with the aforementioned php logic.

PHP:

```
if ($_POST) {
    $username = isset($_POST['username']) ? $_POST['username'] : null;
    $email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
    $password = isset($_POST['password']) ? $_POST['password'] : null;
    if (empty($username) || empty($email) || empty($password)) {
        echo "user registration failed - not all fields filled in!";
    } else {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO 'zz_login' (username, email, password) VALUES ('$username', '$email', '$password')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        if ($result) {
            echo "user registration successful";
        } else {
            echo "user registration failed";
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Right after you require your config and before your if statement do: `echo 'post vars:'; print_r($_POST);` and report what you get

Comment: ... repeating it might help ... all of the above was ignored in the main comments.

Comment: @M_12 If you aren't seeing 'post vars' then I doubt that you are even running the script in the same file. Something should show up even if post isn't working. I suspect you may have an error in your config file. You could try putting the whole echo and print_r before the config and then try submitting the form and see if any post info shows up. As it stands this is working on my localhost perfectly (for lack of a better word): https://pastebin.com/4yUimCt0 ... beyond that it's outside the scope of what I can help you with

Comment: But you just said that $_POST wasn't working, now it somehow is? The only area where that is echoed is in the if section with the $_POST's. Or are you saying its working now?

Comment: If you are using my PHP code then it *could* mean that one or more fields weren't filled in, otherwise if you are using yours that should be what it means - the query failed.

Comment: Yea I am using your PHP code. I complete the whole form and click submit and it still says it failed

Comment: I've updated my above code so that if the registration fails because of a field missing the echo is different. i suggest you do the same and then you will know if you are not getting all the $_post data or if your query has failed. if its the former check to make sure all your name attributes are present and spelled correctly, otherwise its a database issue

Comment: did you remove print_r($_POST) and the echo? that was just for debugging not meant to stay

Comment: I thought you meant the post array from the start where I said to add before config, what are you talking about? What are you seeing? Ofc if you refresh the page it will submit the form, thats the browsers default behavior. If you reload (not refresh) the page it will clear. Just type the url in again or click on the url and hit enter.

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't that complicated find "echo 'post vars:'; print_r($_POST);" wherever it may be and remove it. It's obviously left over from when you were debugging.

Answer (score 0):

you should try 'name=' property in input feild like.

**_POST variable work only on 'name' attribute not in 'id'.**

Comment: once you have enough reputation you can post comments. These forms only comments and not qualified answer